# VSTS Load Testing With JMeter plugin PathNotFoundException?

Tags: visual-studio, jmeter, azure-devops, load-testing

I have created a load test in JMeter to retrieve a valid access token, and then perform several requests to my webAPI to test querying, which works in JMeter.

My test plan uses the JSONPathExtractor plugin to extract the token from the JSON response, before storing that token as a property for use in proceeding Test Groups. **I want to upload and run these JMeter test in Visual Studio Team Services, however I am given an "internal error occurred in the service when initializing the test run".**

Here is the generated log file from VSTS:

```
2016/10/20 13:26:22 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2016/10/20 13:26:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads\0\approot\JMeterLoadTest\clt_jmeterdrop\bin\user.properties 
2016/10/20 13:26:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads\0\approot\JMeterLoadTest\clt_jmeterdrop\bin\system.properties 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.13 r1665067 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_60 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows Server 2012 R2 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.3 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads\0\approot\JMeterLoadTest\clt_jmeterdrop 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\Windows\system32 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\Windows\System32 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.0.0.4 Name: vstsloadagent0 FullName: vstsloadagent0.oykuxugkk15uzmtpoj4pw2mxgh.fx.internal.cloudapp.net 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\Windows\system32' 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='d:\0\td\99ed1\TestRun\Out' 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1656252 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.8 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: d:\0\td\99ed1\TestRun\Out\JMeter Tile Test (Complete).jmx 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2016/10/20 13:26:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/10/20 13:26:23 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'d:\0\td\99ed1\TestRun\Out\JMeter Tile Test (Complete).jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:102)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/hashTree/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 118
version             : 2.13 r1665067
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:586)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:537)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:750)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:737)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:264)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:102)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/hashTree/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor
line number         : 118
version             : 2.13 r1665067
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:97)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:559)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:102)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 59 more
```

It appears that VSTS Load Testing can't find the JSONPathExtractor plugin. How can I include this in my .jmx file or supporting files upload? Many thanks!

Comment: I found problems using JSON Path Extractors with JMeter 2.13 version (same error as above), but working fine with JMeter 3.0, i would suggest you try with 3.0 version

Comment: Hi Naveen! I am currently using JMeter 3.0 (r1743807), I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by the JMeter version since VSTS Load Testing is still using JMeter 2.13 version on the test agent, refer to this link for details: [Apache JMeter tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-jmeter-test#apache-jmeter-tests):

> **Q: What is the supported JMeter version?**
>
> A: The load test agents run Apache JMeter version 2.13, the latest
>   version available currently.

There is already an user voice submitted for this, you can vote it here: [Support jMeter 3.0](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14897391-support-jmeter-3-0).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise this and so switched to JMeter 2.13 to produce tests for VSTS.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your plan depends on 3rd party plugin JSON Path Extractor by JMeter-plugins project.
So you would need to add it as long as its dependencies.

But a better option is to use JMeter 3.0 and the native JSON Post Processor :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor

Comment: Hi, how to add it as long as its dependencies? Could you provide the detail steps. I have the same issue too.

Comment: Make sure to include the plugin .jar file in the 'Support files'

Answer (score 2):

That's not an issue of JMeter or it's version, it's VSTS issue, visual studio doesn't recognize/support JSON Path Extractor used in JMeter script, better to use regular expressions.